# parsing complex json flutter list<map> in list

Tags: json, flutter, parsing

I have a json response where there is a list that contains a list, then there is a map in it, I tried to parse it but it failed, what kind of error did I do? Previously I used this method to parse the map that was in the list and it worked

response json

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": [
        {
            "id_category": 1,
            "category_slug": "cc",
            "category_name": "Credit Card",
            "data_payment": [
                {
                    "payment_slug": "cc",
                    "payment_name": "Credit Card",
                    "payment_logo": "https://cdn.xx.id/assets_midtrans/cc.png"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "message": "Success Get Data"
}
```

mycode

```
class PaymentMethodListModel {
  final String status, message;
  final List<_Data> data;

  PaymentMethodListModel({
    this.status,
    this.message,
    this.data,
  });

  factory PaymentMethodListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> x) {
    var list = x['data'] as List;
    print(list.runtimeType);
    List<_Data> sd = list.map((i) => _Data.fromJson(i)).toList();
    return PaymentMethodListModel(
      status: x['status'],
      data: sd,
      message: x['message'],
    );
  }
}

class _Data {
  final String categorySlug, categoryName;
  final List<DataPayment> dataPayment;
  _Data({
    this.categorySlug,
    this.categoryName,
    this.dataPayment,
  });

  factory _Data.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> obj) {
    var list = obj['data_payment'] as List;
    List<DataPayment> dataPaymentList = list.map((i) => DataPayment.fromJson(i)).toList();

    return _Data(
      categorySlug: obj['category_slug'],
      categoryName: obj['category_name'],
      dataPayment: dataPaymentList,
    );
  }
}

class DataPayment {
  final String paymentSlug, paymentName, paymentLogo;

  DataPayment({
    this.paymentSlug,
    this.paymentName,
    this.paymentLogo,
  });

  factory DataPayment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> x) => DataPayment(
        paymentSlug: x['payment_slug'],
        paymentName: x['payment_name'],
        paymentLogo: x['payment_logo'],
      );
}
```

error message
The method 'map' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: map(Closure: (dynamic) => DataPayment)

Comment: Sometimes it is not necessary to use classes to represent the fetched data, you can just use that data (parsed with `jsonDecode` function) if you understand its structure. If you need to use classes, those ones don't need to be so complex, you only need per class one constructor only (although it depends on your needs). Going back to the case, we need to know the code where you are parsing the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code

`var paymentListModel = PaymentListModel.fromJson(json.decode(str));`

---

```
class PaymentListModel {
    PaymentListModel({
        this.status,
        this.data,
        this.message,
    });

    String status;
    List<Datum> data;
    String message;

    factory PaymentListModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => PaymentListModel(
        status: json["status"],
        data: List<Datum>.from(json["data"].map((x) => Datum.fromJson(x))),
        message: json["message"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "status": status,
        "data": List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())),
        "message": message,
    };
}

class Datum {
    Datum({
        this.idCategory,
        this.categorySlug,
        this.categoryName,
        this.dataPayment,
    });

    int idCategory;
    String categorySlug;
    String categoryName;
    List<DataPayment> dataPayment;

    factory Datum.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Datum(
        idCategory: json["id_category"],
        categorySlug: json["category_slug"],
        categoryName: json["category_name"],
        dataPayment: List<DataPayment>.from(json["data_payment"].map((x) => DataPayment.fromJson(x))),
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id_category": idCategory,
        "category_slug": categorySlug,
        "category_name": categoryName,
        "data_payment": List<dynamic>.from(dataPayment.map((x) => x.toJson())),
    };
}

class DataPayment {
    DataPayment({
        this.paymentSlug,
        this.paymentName,
        this.paymentLogo,
    });

    String paymentSlug;
    String paymentName;
    String paymentLogo;

    factory DataPayment.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => DataPayment(
        paymentSlug: json["payment_slug"],
        paymentName: json["payment_name"],
        paymentLogo: json["payment_logo"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "payment_slug": paymentSlug,
        "payment_name": paymentName,
        "payment_logo": paymentLogo,
    };
}
```